# My friends and I are going to Amsterdam, what can we bring back?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, amsterdam, drugs

My friends and I are going on holiday to Amsterdam in a few months and i was wondering what we could "legally" bring back with us. I have heard stories of people bringing back lollies or tea bags but I am unsure how legal these are, can anyone help me out?

Update: I am flying from England to Amsterdam, going with a group of young adults. I mean marijuana related products when I am referring to tea bags and lollies

Comment: I strongly recommend a good Earl Grey tea, although it's better obtained from England. Clearly there's more to the question you're asking (such as exactly what you mean by "tea bags" and "lollies"), and also where you are from - without that information, nobody can give you a good answer.

Comment: You'll need to look at the rules for marijuana at your destination and any transit points. Also if you're transiting anywhere where the penalty for drugs is death (eg Indonesia) I would suggest not risking it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Even that may not be enough. eg, Marijuana is now legal in Canada, but it's still illegal to bring it into the country.  Plus at this stage it's not even clear that he's not simply talking about a good Darjeeling and a few Yorkie bars!

Comment: You didn't specify your flight destination or transit points, which are important for answering this question. Even some countries which have made cannabis legal to possess still do not allow for its importation (e.g. Canada, USA).

Comment: In all likelihood, the answer is nothing that you can't get in your home country. One can even have issues taking medications which would require a prescription in another country, never mind narcotics. In Canada, importation of cannabis is still illegal (though perhaps there is a permit?), and in the US at a federal level (and CBP is a federal agency) cannabis is not 'legal' even though it is in certain states. Long story short: don't try it.

Answer (score 18):

Nothing.

You can't bring any drug with you, even if it is sold as tea bags, cakes, biscuits, or whatever..

Moreover, since you are in a group of young men coming back from Amsterdam, there is a strong chance that at the UK airport you will be selected for "random" controls. Then if you have taken something illegal with you, you will be in serious troubles.

Answer (score 7):

While it seems 'legal', cannabis and its user ready 'drugs' products are still illegal in the Netherlands.
So there is no 'bought legally' in the Netherlands for any product that can get you high.

There are some weed flavoured items that do not contain the active parts, them you can take home.

For the rest, it is as (il)legal to buy it at home.

The airports are all in 'no tolerance' zones, and as far as I remember, so are the ferries. There is a rather high chance on being selected for further checks when arriving from Amsterdam, more so when traveling as a group of young adults, mostly male.

*Note, this is a slightly stronger point of view than many people claim is legal for use of cannabis within the Netherlands, but that is more opinion than fact when considering export.

Cannabis and the products made of it are 'gedoogd' which translates to 'tolerated when rules are followed but still illegal.' Some people here take the stance that they are not illegal as they are tolerated, I, and many with me, keep to what my (Dutch) gouvernment tells me, they are still illegal within the Netherlands.

Comment: (-1) “Stronger point of view than many people” or, in other words, misleading and uninformative. And by your own admission, this “answer“ only provides “opinion” regarding the question at hand (namely export) so what's the point?

Comment: The difference is in the legal status within the Netherlands, this question and answer are about what you can take to the UK and/or other countries. Your comment misses the point.

Comment: Apparently my previous comment wasn't clear: The main reason for my downvote is precisely that this answer should be but isn't about export and the part that's about it is, by your own admission, pure opinion. So who is missing the point exactly?